# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException while read the json string and map to model object

Tags: java, json, objectmapper

I am trying to read the json String and map to the model object (BusinessModel). The model object is as shown below which has property "`List<LookupData> lookupData;`" and LookupData is the inner class of BusinessModel class and from jsonString i want to map the LookupData .

Below is the sample model class.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonIgnoreProperties
public class BusinessModel {

    private List<LookupData> lookupData;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public static class LoanDescLookup {
        private String id;
        private String description;
        private boolean status;
        private String type;
    }
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @EqualsAndHashCode
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    public static class LookupData {
        private String id;
        private String description;
        private boolean defaultLookup;
        private String regex;
        private String regexDescription;
    }    
}
```

Below is the sample json String.

```
String jsonString = "[\n" +
                    "        {\n" +
                    "            \"id\": \"101\",\n" +
                    "            \"description\": \"issueID 101\",\n" +
                    "            \"defaultLookup\": true,\n" +
                    "            \"regex\": \"^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){4,5}$\",\n" +
                    "            \"regexDescription\": \"A four or five character string, including numbers\"\n" +
                    "        },\n" +
                    "        {\n" +
                    "            \"id\": \"102\",\n" +
                    "            \"description\": \"issueID 102\",\n" +
                    "            \"defaultLookup\": false,\n" +
                    "            \"regex\": \"^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]){4}$\",\n" +
                    "            \"regexDescription\": \"A four character string, including numbers\"\n" +
                    "        },\n" +
                    "        {\n" +
                    "            \"id\": \"103\",\n" +
                    "            \"description\": \"issueID 103\",\n" +
                    "            \"defaultLookup\": false,\n" +
                    "            \"regex\": \"^[A-Z0-9]{11}$\",\n" +
                    "            \"regexDescription\": \"A 11 character vin number\"\n" +
                    "        },\n" +
                    "        {\n" +
                    "            \"id\": \"104\",\n" +
                    "            \"description\": \"issueID 104\",\n" +
                    "            \"defaultLookup\": true,\n" +
                    "            \"regex\": \"^[0-9]{6}$\",\n" +
                    "            \"regexDescription\": \"A 6 character vin number (e.g. 202108)\"\n" +
                    "        }\n" +
                    "    ]";
```

Sample java code to read the above jsonString and map to model object.

```
                ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
                BusinessModel lookupData = om.readValue(jsonString, BusinessModel.class);
              
                for (int i = 0; i < lookupData.getLookupData().size(); i++) {
                    BusinessModel.LookupData selectByLookup = lookupData.getLookupData().get(i);
                    String id = selectByLookup.getId();
                    String description = selectByLookup.getDescription();
                    String regex = selectByLookup.getRegex();
                    String regexDescription = selectByLookup.getRegexDescription();
                    result.add(BusinessModel.selectByLookup.builder().id(id)
                            .description(description)
                            .defaultLookup(result.size() == 0)
                            .regex(regex)
                            .regexDescription(regexDescription)
                            .build());
}
```

Below is the exception i'm getting while running the above code.

```
Exception :: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.model.BusinessModel` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"[
```

Comment: the json you provided doesn't match with the model you are using

Comment: you can use `om.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<LookupData>>(){})`

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in the model class, I have the inner class LookupData which holds the properties mentioned in the json and model class has List<LookupData> as the property as shown in BusinessModel.java

Comment: your model class has property but the json you provided doesn't have that property, if you still don't understand you need to learn how deserialization works